# Prove that summation is less than 1

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, factorial

Prove that $m! \times \sum_{n=m+1}^\infty \frac{1}{n!} < 1$

I started proving this by simplifying it to:
$= m! \times \left(\frac{1}{(m+1)!} + \frac{1}{(m+2)!} + ...\right)$
$= \left(\frac{1}{(m+1)} + \frac{1}{(m+2)(m+1)} + ...\right)$

I'm not too sure how to show that the last step sum is less than 1.

Comment: when $m=0$ you get $e-1 \gt 1$

Comment: @user687319 Note in the RHS of your simplification, your second term should have a factor of $(m+1)$ in the denominator.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If $m\ge 1$

$m!(\frac{1}{(m+1)!}+\frac{1}{(m+2)!}+\frac{1}{(m+3)!}+...)=\frac{1}{m+1}+\frac{1}{(m+2)(m+1)}+\frac{1}{(m+3)(m+2)(m+1)}+...\le \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^2}+...=1$

Comment: +1 for a good answer. However, a minor issue is that the $\le$ before your infinite geometric sum can be a $\lt$ instead, with this then matching what the user is asking to prove.